# How can I access a Velocity template from a sub-subdirectory?

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

I have a velocity template rendering VXML that is located at

```
/billing/billingQuestionsMenu_pp.vm
```

then, in that template, I am forwarding to:

```
<submit next="#springUrl('/billing/billingQuestions/billingQuestionsMenuOption1.vxml')" />
```

Now in my Controller, I have a mapped method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String billingQuestionsMenuOption1(ModelMap model) {
    logger.debug("billingQuestionsMenuOption1");       
    return "/billing/billingQuestions/firstBillMessage_pp";
}
```

I want this method to now call

```
/templates/billing/billingQuestions/firstBillMessage_pp.vm
```

but it does not find it.

now If I change this to be:

```
/templates/billing/firstBillMessage_pp.vm
```

everything works fine.

*** How can I have my templates in a sub-subdirectory? ***

Comment: How's your `ViewResolver` configuration like?

Comment: <bean id="velocityViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityLayoutViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
    <property name="layoutUrl" value="layout/default.vm" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="contentType" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="classpath:/toolbox.xml"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="com.comcast.ivr.agent.web.velocity.VelocityToolsView"/>
</b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one work-around that seems to work by just appending the addition sub-directories for each node:

```
<submit next="#springUrl('/SUBDIRECTORY/billing/billingQuestions/billingQuestionsMenuOption1.vxml')" />
```